# Connecting Minew G1 to Azure IoT

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm working on a project to connect BLE sensors via Minew G1 gateway to Azure IoT Hub, however I'm having trouble registering the device in IoT Hub and establishing the connection from the Minew G1.

Anyone have experience with one of these? Do I need to use X509 certificates or is it possible to use SAS with this device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions maybe helpful. But it depends on the Minew G1's platform, operating system, supported protocol and if it can be installed some software or add customer program etc.

One is using [Azure IoT Hub SDKs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks). For example, there are some out of box packages and libraries for C:

- Linux: Device SDK on apt-get
- mbed: Device SDK library on MBED
- Arduino: Device SDK library in the Arduino IDE
- Windows: Device SDK on NuGet

You can check "[OS Platforms and Hardware Compatibility](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c#os-platforms-and-hardware-compatibility)" to see if your device support.
If not support, you need to [port this library to your device](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c#porting-the-azure-iot-device-client-sdk-for-c-to-new-devices).

Another is using MQTT directly if your device support MQTT protocol but can't use SDKs. [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly) has detailed steps and Python code sample for sending and receiving messages.

**Update:**

> Do I need to use X509 certificates or is it possible to use SAS with
>   this device?

Yes, you can use SAS token for the symmetric key authenticated device. And using x509 certificate for x509 self-signed or x509 CA signed authenticated device also supported. You can choose any one of the authentications when registering the device like this:

[image]

Comment: Using MQTT directly I was able to connect to Azure IoT Hub. Thanks for the tip.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly